# Background image is stretched in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, html

I am using background image for landing page and it works fine on desktop browsers, Android browser but fails on iOS browsers... After looking for answer i thing problem is due to height of the contained div which holds the background image.

I resized the height of the container div using jquery 'var wheight = $(window).height();'

I thing this get length of the whole document and gives feeling of image being streached.

I have setup example on fiddle this may come right on iOS as i have not tested after adding the height using jQuery.

What is the best way to handle this height issue.

SHould i use `screen.height();` or there is a way around for this

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dtphzdxy/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try this in css section

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.bg-intro {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    position:absolute;
}
.bg-intro {
    width:100%;
}
.parallax {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.parallax-1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpapersos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/HD-Wallpaper-Nature.jpg");
    transition: height 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.725, 0, 0, 0.995) 0s;
}
```

Comment: I cant give absolute position to `bg-intro` i hav eto work with relative position and i have other elements at bottom and giving absolute position breaks the design. But this is worth trying...

Answer (score 1):

Window height can be calculated with css using the vh unit. Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dtphzdxy/5/

```
.bg-intro {
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am not aware of `  height:100vh;` what is this `vh`;

Comment: [http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: vh is the viewport height.